# Is "was" correct in "What was the questions?"

Tags: grammar, questions

I saw a poster/plaque with this writing:

> *Wine is the answer. What **was** the questions?*

Is it grammatically right?

My doubt is about the use of ***was***: indeed, if someone asked me to translate in English a such sentence, I would have used the plural form ***were*** because we are talking about question**s**, that is plural!

Comment: Wine could be the answer to any number of questions.  Enough wine answers why we might forget the beginning of a sentence by the time we reach -- um, where were we going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the designer of the poster intentionally wanted to use the plural *question**s***, then **were** would indeed be grammatically correct, and we would be left with the following jarring phrase:

> Wine is the answer. What were the questions?

However, given the obvious attempt at humour, I would assert that using the plural is in fact a typo, and that the phrase should read:

> Wine is the answer. What was the question?

Comment: But given the attempted humor, the disagreement in number might also be intentional: the person is too drunk to get even the basics correct.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo An interesting interpretation!